# findstr: Extract value from key pair

Tags: windows, cmd, findstr, key-pair

For example :

```
echo key=1 | findstr key
```

How get `1` from pair via `findstr`.
Please avoid ugly `for`, `delims` or something, if possible.

Comment: Why avoid `for`? It is native to batch files, what is the problem with it? findstr is a .exe and less native.

Comment: Ok, how with `for`?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ("key=1") do echo %a`. `findstr` *always* returns the whole line (no splitting functionality)

Comment: why this not work:
`for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('echo key=1') do echo %a` - in command_line (not script)

Comment: Because = is one of the special characters and gets eaten

Comment: What to do with it ?

Comment: escape it: `... in ('echo key^=1') do ...` or save them in quotes (in this case quoting the whole command): `... in ('"echo key=1"') do ...`

Comment: The method choice would depend upon where the key pair is coming from and how. Could you please [edit] your question to provide that information.

Comment: @Compo
Why would I edit the question if it already states where the data is coming from?

Comment: It doesn't your example is `echo key=1` which means you could have just used `echo 1`. So what you need to do is explain where `key=1` is really coming from, in the context of the real task.

Comment: From pipe, omg !

Comment: There is no command in `cmd` that can split a string from a pipe (afaik). You need an external utility, like `echo key=2 | jrepl "key=(\d*)" "$1" /A`, using Dbenham's [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)